# Android: Viewing video stream from url

Tags: java, android, stream, iot

I'm trying to make an app, that streams video from remote camera built on microcontroller. It connects to controllers softAP. On basic adress of controller (192.168.4.1:80) is video stream from its camera. I would like to show it in app.

I've tried WebView, but it don't work. DNS config problem appears. Now I try to do it with VideoView, but it only shows black screen. 
How can I open it, without any control buttons. Just plain stream.

My code:

```
public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_web_view);
        VideoView main = new VideoView(this);
        Uri url = Uri.parse("192.168.4.1:80");
        main.setVideoURI(url);
        main.start();
    }
}
```

xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".WebViewActivity">

    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/webview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try ExoPlayer.
And its sources: https://exoplayer.dev/media-sources.html

Comment: I would like not to use external libraries.

Comment: ExoPlayer is most powerful library from Google that has much useful features for media streams. Its recommended for media streaming.

Comment: Content-Type: image/jpeg, I don't see ant solution for this in Exo.

Comment: You need video stream. For images use ImageView. Or if you want combine image and video — create your own custom ViewGroup with right visibility logic for views.